# Eloquent where clause on with table

Tags: laravel-4

I have a `Quote` Eloquent model which has several relationships, one of them being `Customer`. I'm writing a search controller which takes a query and then searches the models. If I don't need to search on the custom relationship I can easily do this:

```
$Quote = Quote::where('trashed', '0'); // Never get trashed items.
$Quote->where('item', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
```

Works a treat.

However, if I want to search all quotes, but by the customers name:

```
$Quote = Quote::where('trashed', '0'); // Never get trashed items.    
$Quote = $Quote->with(['Customer' => function($Query) use ($searchQuery) {
    $Query->where('e_mail', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
}]);
```

All this is doing is saying "join the customers that have a name like `$searchQuery`. If I move the `where` clause to be after the `with` method, it can't access the `e_mail` field.

So how do I search the quotes, but where the customer is equal to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using `whereHas` instead of `with`, with a query.

```
$Quote = Quote::whereHas('customer', function($Query) use($searchQuery) {
    $Query->where('e_mail', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
});
```

Sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Quote = Quote::with(['Customer' => function($Query) use ($searchQuery) {
             $Query->where('e_mail', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
         }])->where('trashed', '0')->where('item', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
```

Comment: Almost. This is only returning customers linked to quotes that have the matching information. I need "Quotes" whose "Customers" have these emails.

Comment: I've set my code up to be this: `$Quote = Quote::with(['Customer' => function($Query) use ($searchQuery) {
   $Query->where('e_mail', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
  }])->where('trashed', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');` but it's not performing the `e_mail` part.